# Windows RDP with AWS EC2 - used to include password, now doesn't

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

I haven't logged on to my EC2 recently in a few months.  Last time I did, it seems like the RDP file that I downloaded had the password in it. That laptop died.

Today, it seems like AWS/EC2 has changed how things work.  I'm able to download the RDP file, but it is prompting for a password.  When I try to decrypt the password, it wants me to paste or browse to a file on my disk, which I don't have.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to re-download my key info?  On security then "Key Pairs", I see the key for this server.  Can I download that to my disk, or open it somehow?

I see these steps, but they look overwhelming, i.e. I don't have time for that now; I have real work to do:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html

I was able to create a new key pair, but not sure if I can associate it with the instance.

When I click "Get Password" this screen appears:

UPDATE 1: I did find my .pem file, so I was able to use that to logon.
Had I not found it, what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE 1: I did find my .pem file, so I was able to use that to logon. Had I not found it, what would I do?

Not much really! This is by design. AWS doesn't store your encryption key, and this prevents AWS personnel to access your instance. That's why you get such an ominous warning when pem file is generated: this is your one and only opportunity to see it - don't lose it.

That said, there are several *however*.
If you changed your Windows password in windows, or created a new AMI and launched a new instance from it - the pem file won't really help. You can probably create 2 administrator accounts; so if one forgets their password, you can reset it with another one.

Second - if your EBS is not encrypted, you can detach it, launch another instance, and attach EBS to new instance. You won't get your instance back, but you will get the data from that drive.

Finally, the "overwhelming" steps from the link that you posted. Follow good security posture, and you won't need them. But if you get sloppy, it may become your real work... better than polishing a resume...

Comment: Did they change the process recently.  Like I said, a few months ago, I could download the RDP file, click it, and I think it just logged on with the password included.

Comment: I don't think so... I can't imagine that RDP that you download later would have password. AWS doesn't have information to generate the password. It needs pem file that you have to provide